# Representations of $O(2)$ and related problems

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm currently studying Group Theory in order make a further application to physics and understand the math of some physical theories.

I know that $SO(2)$ literally is a special case for $O(2)$ and that its regular representation is a rotation matrix but it can be reduced to $e^{i\theta}$ since it is a abelian group. But what about $O(2)$? what are its regular and irreducible representations?

Since $SO(2)$ is much more widely used than $O(2)$ (at least it seems to) I'm having trouble finding answers about this question of mine.

Comment: O(2) also contains reflections and it does have 2-dimensional irreps.  The book by Wu-Ki Tung on Group Theory has a good chapter on this.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?